# Links and tooltips in Diablo III questions

Tags: discussion, diablo-3

Diablo III is about to come out, and I anticipate a lot of questions about it. These questions (and their answers) are likely to refer to skills and items from the game, so they are likely to link to them.

There are multiple places where one can link to, such as the official [Diablo III Game Guide](http://battle.net/d3/en/game/) and the unofficial [DiabloWiki](http://www.diablowiki.com/Diablo_III_Wiki) or [Diablo III Database](http://d3db.com/home). Furthermore, some of these sites publish a script which can be used to add tooltips when hovering over links pointing to them, something which could be very useful in this site.

There was a meta-discussion regarding [which resource site to use with Terraria](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2376/terraria-wiki-or-wikia-links), and while I'm not sure it's something we'd want to enforce, I would like to encourage our active members to be consistent in their links with D3 as well. I think it's best to use the official site - not because I think it's better, simply because I have more trust in these links being more resistant to link rot.

In addition, that means that **whoever is interested in the game can install [this userscript for Gaming SE](https://stackapps.com/questions/3399/diablo-iiis-tooltip-script-for-gaming-stack-exchange) and enjoy the tooltips whenever there's a link to the official site.**

Comment: DiabloWiki is a Curse property. It should be fairly resistant to link rot as well, for those links for which the official database is in some way inappropriate.

Comment: @bwarner works for me with Chrome on Mac on PC... what's your OS and browser?

Comment: Never mind, I restarted the browser and now its working again.  Must've just been some local issue.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that we should use the official site.  It sounds like it is pulling the numbers directly from the Battle.Net data files, so it should be up to date reliably.  The only benefit of the other sites is that they may have more information about a skill than what Blizzard is officially telling people, but I think that would go away over time.

Does the official site have a tooltip script like you were mentioning?

Comment: Yes; [the userscript which I've made for Gaming.SE](http://stackapps.com/questions/3399/diablo-iiis-tooltip-script-for-gaming-stack-exchange) - also linked above - uses it.

Comment: Doh, reading fail.

Comment: Just browsing a few randomly selected entries for differences, there are a few pieces of data on DiabloWiki that are not on the official site. For items, these include Item Level and Sell Price. B3DB meanwhile, includes a list of known available affixes and their magnitudes, which neither of the others offer. None of these is important enough to justify the use of a third party site over b.net just yet, but both are worth being aware of.